# How does GitLab handle stranded (orphaned) artifacts in Object Store?

Tags: gitlab, backup

If I have a two minio clusters,

- one running in production and,
- one running as a hot-backup streaming with `mc mirror`,

And, if I have a point-in-time-backup running `gitaly-backup`. What happens if new artifacts are added *after* `gitaly-backup` is run? Are they effectively stranded? Does GitLab prune them by default? And if not, can I trigger a rpruning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `gitlab:cleanup`

In order to clean up artifact storage post-restoration you'll need to run the following from the [gitlab:cleanup](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/raketasks/cleanup.md), (you may want to try without `DRY_RUN=false` first).

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:cleanup:orphan_job_artifact_files DRY_RUN=false
```

In the same light, you also remove uploaded files after the PITR backup,

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:cleanup:project_uploads
```